# Print Looping for dynamic row php

Tags: php

please help me , im newbie , and i have a problem . 
My code is .

```
$angka=5;
$k=0;
$sum=1;
echo "<br/>";
echo "Hasil :";
echo "<br/>";
for($i=1; $i<=$angka; $i++) {
    for($j=1; $j<=$angka; $j++-6+1) {
        $k+=$sum;

        echo $k;


    }


    $k+=$sum;

    $sum*=-1;
}
?>
```

I want the result is like this .

15151
24242
33333
42424
51515

Comment: "i have a problem" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: Can you provide a *precise* specification of what it is that you want to happen, including any and all rules, exceptions from those rules, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Can you provide sample inputs and outputs demonstrating what you expect to happen, both in normal cases, and in all the exceptions, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Please, also make sure to provide a [mcve].

Comment: the result not my expecting , the result in my code is 
12345
54321
12345
54321
12345

 i want for the result like this . 

15151
24242
33333
42424
51515

sorry , my language not good for explain to you -_-

Comment: Please, don't put important information in comments, put it in the question. Please, don't give just a single example of input and output, instead specify the *rules* how that output is derived from the input. I, for one, don't understand what rule leads to that output from your input. When describing the rules, don't forget to also include all exceptions, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases. When giving examples, give *multiple* examples, both demonstrating the normal rules as well as demonstrating the exceptions, special cases, and border cases. E.g. what should the …

Comment: … output be if the input is empty? What if it is `0`? What if it is `'Hello'`? Also, please make sure that your code is properly indented, uses readable variable and function names that clearly explain the purpose of the code (for example, I don't understand what `$sum` does), and that your code is well-documented and well-tested. Make sure that your code is minimal and doesn't contain anything that is not absolutely required to demonstrate your problem. Explain what you have tried to debug this, so that we don't unnecessarily duplicate all the hard work you have already done.

Comment: forgive me jorg, i lack the detail in explaining the problem that i face. but this problem has been aided by joshua, thank you for helping me how the rules in asking in this forum. thanks again jorg.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello i think this answer is working.

```
<?php
    echo 'Expected Result:<br>';
    echo '15151 24242 33333 42424 51515';

    echo '<br>';
    echo "<br/>";
    echo "Hasil :";
    echo "<br/>";

    $start = 1;
    $angka = 5;
    $a = $angka;
    for($i=$start; $i<=$angka; $i++) {
        for($j=$start;$j<=$angka;$j=$j+2){
            echo $i;
            if($j < $angka) echo $a;
        }
        $a--;
        echo ' ';
    }
?>
```

Result:

```
Expected Result:
15151 24242 33333 42424 51515

Hasil :
15151 24242 33333 42424 51515
```

Comment: thanks josua , this is what i mean, thanks again for you .